# How do I delete a record in django_admin_log?

Tags: django

So I have been making some (big) changes in my `User` model, and somehow got this error : `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'django_admin_log' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: django_admin_log.user_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in member_user.id.`

The cause of the error is the superuser I created. But then I changed my `User` model from Django's built-in model to custom model.
I'm trying to delete the record from the table `django_admin_log` which has `user_id` equal to 1. How do I do this? Thanks in advance.